# (C#) If-Else Statement Issue

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program which calculates the price of different fruits in different days. I have two fruits available now (banana and apple). When I type "apple", the week day and the quantity it gives the price for the apple only. The problem is that when I type "banana", the weekday and the quantity it gives me the price for both banana and apple.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FruitShop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fruit = Console.ReadLine();
            var weekday = Console.ReadLine();
            var quantuty = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (fruit == "banana")
            {
                if (weekday != "saturday" && weekday != "sunday")
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.50);

                 if (weekday == "saturday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.70);
                }
                 if (weekday == "sunday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.70);
                }
            }






           else if (fruit == "apple")
            {
                if (weekday != "saturday" && weekday != "sunday")
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.20);
            }

            {
                 if (weekday == "saturday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.25);
                }
                 if (weekday == "sunday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.25);
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are Saturday and Sunday cases are not inside the apple else-if condition braces.

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I should double check my syntax next time :)

Comment: Look into using [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) (free) or ReSharper (pay) - they will point out ambiguous formatting that can lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

i noticed that you made a mistake on the use of braces. You can see that when you look to else if declaration. All the if statements corresponding to "apple" should be within the else-if braces. I dont know if you got it by my description, but try to see it on the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FruitShop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type a fruit name:");
            var fruit = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Type a week's day:");
            var weekday = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Type a quantity:");
            var quantuty = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (fruit == "banana")
            {
                if (weekday != "saturday" && weekday != "sunday")
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.50);

                 if (weekday == "saturday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.70);
                }
                 if (weekday == "sunday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.70);
                }
            }
            //Here. All the if's should be inside this main else-if
            else if (fruit == "apple")
            {
                if (weekday != "saturday" && weekday != "sunday")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.20);
                }

                 if (weekday == "saturday")
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.25);
                 }
                 if (weekday == "sunday")
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.25);
                 }
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I hope that i addressed your query

Answer (score 0):

shorter

```
if (fruit == "banana")
{
     if (weekday == "saturday")
        Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.70);
     else if (weekday == "sunday")
        Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.70);
     else 
        Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 2.50);
}
else if (fruit == "apple")
{
     if (weekday == "saturday")
        Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.25);
     else if (weekday == "sunday")
        Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.25);
     else 
        Console.WriteLine(quantuty * 1.20);
}
```